# Vectorization of false peak detection solution

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

Assume time signal `x` of size `1xN` assumed to be a sinusoid. Performing peak detection on this, I expect the output to be alternatingly positive/negative, and in the case of "false peaks" (can occur due to noise in signal), I want to average the sequence.

Input is `[locs, pks]` and an example could be:

```
locs = [ 10   20  30   38   40   42  50   60   ]; 
 pks = [  2.3 -1.2 0.5 -1.6 -1.4 -1.5 0.3 -0.5 ];
```

In which case, I would like to collect peak numbers 4 through 6 to a combined `loc = mean([38 40 42]) = 40` and `pk = mean([-1.6 -1.4 -1.5]) = -1.5`. A working algorithm is:

```
labels = bwlabel(diff(sign(pks)) == 0);
ulabels = 1:max(labels);

for i = 1:length(ulabels)
    idx = find(labels==ulabels(i));
    idx = [idx, idx(end)+1];
    locs(idx(1)) = round(mean(locs(idx)));
    pks(idx(1)) = mean(pks(idx));
    locs(idx(2:end)) = nan;
    pks(idx(2:end)) = nan;
end

locs = locs(~isnan(locs));
pks = pks(~isnan(pks));
```

However, due to the `for` loop this is very slow if there are many false peaks, and it will be ran **many** times in my entire script. I am looking to speed it up.

*Therefore: How could I vectorize this problem?*

Thanks.

Comment: I dont understand why you are doing peak detection the way you do. vectorization aside, the algorithm you use is very inefficient. First, you should smooth your data before any peak detection takes place. you can use `smooth` or `conv` and\or `medfilt1` etc.  Also, are you interested in finding "negative" peaks? there are not peaks so why are you "expect the output to be alternatively positive/negative"?

Comment: @bla I do not understand your comment. The above algorithm assumes input is a previous peak detection, but the signal might contain noise, and I want to find "false peaks", and remove the impact of them.